# ASP.NET Core - Let's Encrypt - No credentials are available in the security package while creating certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to get **Let's Encrypt** certificate through ACME protocol for my web application by using **[Lettuce Encrypt](https://github.com/natemcmaster/LettuceEncrypt)**.
I'm facing an issue (underlined in red bellow) while starting my application, and requesting a new certificate :

> Win32Exception (0x8009030E): No credentials are available in the security package

[No credentials are available in the security package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA65p.png)

My application is running as a Windows service (not with IIS).
I configured Lettuce Encrypt this way in my **Startup.cs** file :

```
services.AddLettuceEncrypt().PersistDataToDirectory(new DirectoryInfo(certDirectory), "MyPfxPassword");
```

I'm trying to figure out where is my mistake. Could someone please help me about this topic ?

Comment: We are nott alone getting this error  https://github.com/natemcmaster/LettuceEncrypt/issues/161
I can't even access the method PersistDataToDirectory( ..)